# I can't add a flare splash screen to y app

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

[Here's my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxmTP.png)

When i try to run the code i get the error

> error: The argument type 'HomePage Function(dynamic)' can't be
>   assigned to the parameter type 'Widget'. (argument_type_not_assignable
>   at [ttt] lib\main.dart:37)

Here' the full code

```
return
  MaterialApp(

 home: SplashScreen.navigate(
 name: 'tic.flr',
 next: (context) => HomePage(),
 until: () => Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5)),
 startAnimation: '1',
 ),
 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to only pass the widget ? So :

```
next: HomePage(),
```